# PyCharm Cython debugger extension compilation - gcc failure

Tags: python, gcc, pycharm, cython

I'm having some trouble compiling the Cython debugger extension in PyCharm on Ubuntu 17.04.  When I start a debugger session, the "Python Debugger Extension Available" popup appears; but every time I click Install, I get a dialog box saying:

```
Non-zero exit code (1):
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have the Gnu C Compiler installed:

```
$ which x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
$ ls -l /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Apr 29 14:02 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-6
```

I'm using Python 3.5:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

I've installed the Python developer library:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.5.3-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Any advice gratefully appreciated!

Huw

Comment: The actual error message will be found prior to the part you have posted. It might be swallowed by the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.  Turns out my project was configured for Python 3.6:

[image]